# Log binding context for HTML element when using Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

For a site using knockout.js you could select an element in chrome with the picker (dev tools) and then write in the console `ko.contextFor($0)` is there an eqivalent in Aurelia that would let me see the binding context for an HTML element?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Chrome addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aurelia-inspector/ofemgdknaajmpeoblfdjkenbpcfbdefg) exactly for that ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/aurelia/inspector)).

Comment: That looks pretty cool and there was one for knockout too. If I didn't want to use the addon is there a way to do it from the console as I described too?

Comment: Ahh you have linked the source code i'll dig around in there. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code from the chrome addon it seems that `$0.au` gives a decent amount of information.

To get the binding context you can find it with `$0.au.show.scope.bindingContext`

Comment: Note, this doesn't seem to work for content inside a components `<slot></slot>`

Comment: perhaps that's worth reporting as an issue.